# How to make Ubuntu + Apache + mpm-worker + mod_php + APC?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I want to make web server for high load on Ubuntu. I use nginx for frontend and apache for backend.

And as you probably guessed I was not able to gather Apache (worker) + mod_php + APC, because it is not possible under Ubuntu with apt-get install.

How can I do this?

- If you want to propose to collect from the source, please give the exact instruction
- Please do not offer to use fastcgi

Comment: Why no Fast CGI?

Answer (score 1):

Although, you don't want fcgi, it is the way to go here. Mixing threaded and non-threaded is not very clever.

Not all PHP modules are thread safe and you would want that with MPM worker. You can, if you compile by hand, force it to go together but you **will** run into problems with it.

The symptoms you will see is Apache blowing up sometimes and segmentation faults.

PHP needs space for execution and you can do that with prefork+mod_php or worker+fcgi.

Yes, I allow myself to post this as an answer, even if I know that this isn't the answer you really want.